# get trustWallet account info using python web3 and mnemonic phrase

Tags: web3.py, python, trustwallet

I do not think I have chosen the best title, but here we go with the main question:

GOAL: I have my 12 word mnemonic phrase, but not in the actual correct order. So, I want to write a script to take a mnemonic phrase, try to connect to the account using the phrase, and then return the balance of the account amonside with private_key or account address, etc.; and then append the correct order of the phrase in the `final_list`.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

I have come so far to use web3 and eth_account packages as below:

```
from web3 import Web3
from eth_account import Account
import itertools
from eth_utils.exceptions import ValidationError
import time
import datetime

Account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()
web3 = Web3(
    Web3.HTTPProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/###API_KEY###")
)
```

Then, I have this function which is supposed to return the account balance:

```
def check_balance(mnemonic_phrase):

    # Derive the private key from the mnemonic phrase
    account = Account.from_mnemonic(mnemonic_phrase)

    # Get the Ethereum address associated with the account
    address = account.address

    # Get the balance of the address
    balance_wei = web3.eth.get_balance(address)

    # Convert the balance from wei to Ether
    balance_eth = web3.from_wei(balance_wei, "ether")

    return balance_eth
```

But the problem is that, whenever I try to loop over the possible combinations of mnemonic phrases and test them, the first line in the function, `account = Account.from_mnemonic(mnemonic_phrase)` sometimes returns an account even for the wrong combination of the words (the words are correct, but maybe the 11th and the 12th words are misplaced).

```
start_all_time = time.time()
for batch in batch_generator:
    start_batch_time = time.time()

    for mnemonic in batch:
        try:
            balance = check_balance(mnemonic)

            final_list.append(mnemonic)

        except ValidationError:
            count = count + 1
            continue
    print(f"One batch is completed in {time.time() - start_batch_time}!")
```

It was strange to see a lot of final candidates in the `final_list`, as I was expecting to only one combination to be accepted, not many of them.
Then I took a look at the function docstring:

```
@combomethod
def from_mnemonic(
    self,
    mnemonic: str,
    passphrase: str = "",
    account_path: str = ETHEREUM_DEFAULT_PATH,
) -> LocalAccount:
    """
    Generate an account from a mnemonic.

    .. CAUTION:: This feature is experimental, unaudited, and likely to change soon

    :param str mnemonic: space-separated list of BIP39 mnemonic seed words
    :param str passphrase: Optional passphrase used to encrypt the mnemonic
    :param str account_path: Specify an alternate HD path for deriving the seed
        using BIP32 HD wallet key derivation.
    :return: object with methods for signing and encrypting
    :rtype: LocalAccount
```

As you see, it says it is experimental and so on.

Can anyone tell me any other method to get the account info only from the correct combination of mnemonic 12 words? Or can anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong here?

Comment: `experimental` this has been experimental since 2016 and every project in the world uses it. The code should work fine. The comment is old comment for a project that sees very little open source maintenance.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa So why is that this functions is still givving results for slightly wrong combinations?

Comment: The function has worked fine for me. Unfortunately your question does not include repeatable steps to help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question to include necessary details.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I added a few more details to the question, can you please look at that again to see if it is clear enough?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I added a bounty to this question, I appreciate your time and help in advanced. Thank you for any input.

Comment: There will always be candidates in your list. Any combination of seed words to create a seed phrase is technically a valid seed phrase. What's going to make your life harder now though, is that each mnemonic technically has unlimited accounts associated with it as well. It seems like your approach is ok, but your loop is going to run for a long time.

Comment: @PatrickCollins Thanks for the input. Do you think celery could help me? Maybe I use a strong vps alongside with celery to create multiple workers and at least reduce the time by the number of workers.

Comment: @Vahid, as Patrick has mentioned "**each mnemonic technically has unlimited accounts associated with it**", and by default `Account.from_mnemonic()` function returns only the very first account i.e., being created using that mnemonic. And, any combination of words of a valid mnemonic, will generate an address. So, it would make sense to filter that on the basis of desired wallet address(es) as well, before putting the valid mnemonics into the `final_list`, so as to have a targeted subset. Even, further you can put a check for `>0` transaction counts, so as to make sure that address is active.

Comment: @SYEDASADKAZMI You make a valid point, but I stil do not understand one part here. " filter that on the basis of desired wallet address(es) " what do you mean by "desired addresses?" How can I specify which addresses I desire?

Comment: @Vahid, I mean, if you're targeting a particular wallet address corresponding to a mnemonic, against which you want to check balance.

Comment: @Vahid, I think you're not having any such targeted address, because if you do, then you wouldn't need to generate addresses from mnemonic at first place, in order to check the balances. Right?

Comment: @SYEDASADKAZMI
Yes exactly, I know the words for the account, but i do not know the correct order of the combination. So, I am looking for a way to access the account. Now, I want to loop over the combinations using something like celery, and check each combination to see whether they have a balance more than 10$. This is the only method I have managed to find so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152228/discussion-between-vahid-and-syed-asad-kazmi).

Comment: As others have mentioned, each seed will generate a valid address. Furthermore, numerous addresses are possible for each seed depending on the wallet used. The number of potential seeds is 12!, equating to 479,001,600 possible accounts. However, it may be impractical to check this vast number of accounts through a public RPC. You can estimate speed by testing thousands of tries and estimating the time required for 12!. If you lack additional information (such as an address), the most feasible solution is to run a local node, and search locally for valid seeds faster.

Comment: To make my comment more accurate, I should add two notes.
1. a very small fraction of this 12! possible addresses can be eliminated due a checksum in seed.
2. check whether your python implementation make similar address to TrustWallet for the same seed. Wallets can have different driven address from the same seed.

Comment: Dear @Ehsan, thank you for your comment, but I lack technical info regarding the things you said. Can you please elaborate them more in an answer providing a sample code? It would also be nice of you if you give some articles on the phrases you mentioned (e.g. seed, what is checksum in seed, etc)?